docker-compose -e flag does not override default value
I have created the following docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    image: my-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /src
    command: python ${SCRIPT}
    environment:
      - .env

  app-dev:
    extends:
      service: app
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src

My .env file has one line:
SCRIPT=./tutorial_00/docker_test.py

I will now do the following steps:

Build the docker image: docker-compose up --build  app
This will build the image and run the docker_test.py script
Now I want to run a different python script using this command: docker-compose run --rm -e SCRIPT=tutorial_01/main.py app
This should override the default value for the SCRIPT variable which was retrieved from the .env file with tutorial_01/main.py. However it ignores this flag and still runs the default script. I don't really know why. It seems like the parameter is completely ignored.

If I run the following command docker-compose run --rm -e SCRIPT=./tutorial_01/main.py app env it shows me that the variable was set successfully:
PATH=/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=e420aa256ae69
TERM=xterm
SCRIPT=./tutorial_01/main.py
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=A035C8C19219BA821E8D684696D
PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.9
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=24.0
PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=65.5.1

If I set ./tutorial_01/main.py as the default value in .env it successfully runs this file instead. So the path is definetly valid.

When talking about compose and environment variables, you have to be careful about if the variables are for compose or for the container.
The -e option with docker compose run is for the container. So when you run
docker-compose run --rm -e SCRIPT=./tutorial_01/main.py app env

the SCRIPT variable is set inside the container and is not available in the compose file.
To make a variable available to compose, you can set it on the host. If you do do
SCRIPT=./tutorial_01/main.py docker-compose run --rm app env

the script variable is set on the host, docker compose has access to it and your compose file will work as expected.

Thanks for clarification. That explains why it only accepted the default value from my .env file when it was called just that. Every other name did not work. Because .env gets picked up by the host automatically but every other file name does not. So I just deleted the environment block from docker-compose and it runs fine now with your solution.

The correct syntax to include a env file is "env_file:" not "environment".
Also, Docker compose already expands $ variables in the compose.yaml using the docker cli environment AND implicitly any .env file in the same folder.
To write a script inline in the compose.yaml that references container variables you need to escape $ as $$.
To demonstrate:
.env
FOO=bar

test.env
FOO=test

compose.yaml
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    env_file:
      - test.env
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      echo compose FOO=$FOO
      echo container FOO=$$FOO

# show the defaults
$ docker compose run test
compose FOO=bar
container FOO=test
# override the variable in the container.
$ docker compose -e FOO=cli run test
compose FOO=bar
container FOO=cli
# override the implicit .env
$ FOO=override docker compose run test
compose FOO=override
container FOO=test


EDIT:
A real answer was given and marked as such. I'm just leaving this here fyi. However I'd not recommend doing it this way. Use the solution provided by "Hans Kilian" instead.
I experimented a little bit and I'm starting to think that variables inside the command: block are not possible. I assume the command you are actually running has to be static. Therefore I am using the following workaround. I run a static file which will run the correct file for me based on the given environment variable. I updated the docker-compose.yml as follows:
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    image: my-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /src
    command: python start.py
    environment:
      - SCRIPT=./tutorial_00/docker_test.py

  app-dev:
    extends:
      service: app
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src

Then I created a new python file called start.py inside my docker src directory which will get the ENV SCRIPT and runs a python file at that location:
import os
import subprocess
import sys


def main():
    # Retrieve the environment variable 'SCRIPT'
    script_path = os.getenv('SCRIPT')

    if not script_path:
        print("Error: The 'SCRIPT' environment variable is not set.")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(script_path):
        print(f"Error: The file at '{script_path}' does not exist.")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Execute the Python script
    try:
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, script_path], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(
            f"Error: The script at '{script_path}' failed with exit code {e.returncode}.")
        sys.exit(e.returncode)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Now I can successfully run any python script by passing the SCRIPT variable during the docker-compose run command:
docker-compose run --rm -e SCRIPT=tutorial_02/main.py app

This definitely works but it feels like a bit of a "shady" workaround. Let me know if there is a better way to do this.

The normal use of docker-compose run is to provide an alternate command to run as part of that command line.  So if you ran
docker-compose run app ./tutorial_00/docker_test.py

then (assuming the script is correctly marked executable and has a correct shebang line) it will run the script instead of the Compose file command: override, and instead of the Dockerfile CMD.
This means you don't need an environment variable to specify the command to run, since Docker already has a native way to provide that.  You can also safely rely on the Dockerfile's WORKDIR and CMD to provide a default working directory and command; you don't need to override these in the Compose file.  You should be able to reduce the Compose file to only
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - .env

